# MySQL Union all combine with MySQL Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I want to get the description and model from `allinventory_tb`.

So I did inner join but when I'm going to display description and model.

**The error is this:**

> Notice: Undefined index: description , Notice: Undefined index: model.

Any suggestions?

```
  |allinventory_tb|
  ----------------
  |in_code        |
  |description    |
  |model          |
  ---------------
    $sql = "select t.itemcode  as itemcode ,sum(t.qty) as qty
    from ( 
    select itemcode,qty  from barcode INNER JOIN allinventory_tb on barcode.itemcode = allinventory_tb.in_code
    union all
    select itemcode,qty from adjustment_tb INNER JOIN allinventory_tb on adjustment_tb.itemcode = allinventory_tb.in_code where adjustment_tb.status='APPROVED'
    union all
    select itemcode,(qty * -1) from soldout_pd INNER JOIN allinventory_tb on soldout_pd.itemcode = allinventory_tb.in_code) as t
    group by itemcode";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Your error looks like it is coming from PHP rather than MySQL.  Does the raw query run in MySQL without error?  What error does the console give you?

Comment: Query is running without error , the error will display if im going to display the row in allinvty_tb though i already did the INNER JOIN thing.

Comment: Can you _please_ consistently refer to your table names?  I see _three_ versions of the name just in your question alone: `allinventory_tb`, `allinvty3`, and `allinvty_tb`.

Comment: sorry .my code is already updated.

Answer (score 1):

**With your Query i.e.**

```
$sql = "select t.itemcode  as itemcode ,sum(t.qty) as qty
    from ( 
    select itemcode,qty  from barcode INNER JOIN allinventory_tb on barcode.itemcode = allinventory_tb.in_code
    union all
    select itemcode,qty from adjustment_tb INNER JOIN allinventory_tb on adjustment_tb.itemcode = allinventory_tb.in_code where adjustment_tb.status='APPROVED'
    union all
    select itemcode,(qty * -1) from soldout_pd INNER JOIN allinventory_tb on soldout_pd.itemcode = allinventory_tb.in_code) as t
    group by itemcode";


    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

You will not able to access description and model column value because your are not specify desire column name in your query so when you try to access query result in PHP you will get Notice Error like:

> Notice: Undefined index: description , Notice: Undefined index: model.

**Try this query**

```
$sql = "select description,model,t.itemcode  as itemcode ,sum(t.qty) as qty
    from ( 
    select description,model,itemcode,qty  from barcode as bc INNER JOIN allinventory_tb as ait on bc.itemcode = ait.in_code
    union all
    select description,model,itemcode,qty from adjustment_tb as adt INNER JOIN allinventory_tb as ait1 on adt.itemcode = ait1.in_code where adjustment_tb.status='APPROVED'
    union all
    select description,model,itemcode,(qty * -1) from soldout_pd as slp INNER JOIN allinventory_tb as ait2 on slp.itemcode = ait2.in_code) as t
    group by itemcode";


$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Hope this works for you...

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. i already check it.

Comment: @codeSeven can you post your var_dump() result based on the above query. I think you are accessing it wrongly.

Comment: I agree with @FaisalMohmand please post your var_dump() result